# How to prove that a group affords no epimorphism in $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, group-presentation, epimorphisms

Good evening,

I want to prove that the group $G = \langle a, d \mid a d a^{-1} d a = d a d^{-1} a d \rangle$ affords no epimorphism in $S_3$ (the group of the permutations of $\{1, 2, 3\}$). I tried many frequent tools to prove that groups afford no morphism (orders of elements, etc...), but it didn't work.

How may I proceed?

Thank you very much,

Respectfully,

AF

Comment: Since the presentation is symmetric in $a$ and $b$, you can easily reduce to the two cases $a \mapsto (1,2,3)$, $d \mapsto (1,2)$; and $a\mapsto (1,2)$, $d \mapsto(2,3)$. Then you just need to check that neither of those satisfies the group relation. (You could do it by computer using GAP.)

Comment: @DerekHolt: By left multiplying by $d^{-1}$ and right multiplying by $a^{-1}$, the relation may be rewritten as $(d^{-1}ada^{-1})d=a(d^{-1}ada^{-1})$, which implies that $a$ and $d$ are conjugate. This means that you only need to check your second case. Write $[a]$ for $(1\;2)$ and $[d]$ for $(2\;3)$. Since $[a]=[a]^{-1}$ and $[d]=[d]^{-1}$,  the relation forces $([a][d])^5=1$, hence $[a]=[d]$, which is false.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. Once proven that we can reduce the problem to the said two cases, it's easy. Yet I don't understand the first part, namely why the presentation being symmetric enables to reduce to these two cases ...

Comment: @ArthurFilippi I just meant that the third possibility $a \mapsto (1,2)$, $d \mapsto (1,2,3)$ is essentially the same as the first because of the symmetry between $a$ and $d$. But Keith Kearnes has shown that we only need consider $a \mapsto (1,2)$, $d \mapsto (2,3)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, but why don't we have to consider $a \longmapsto (1, 2), d \longmapsto (1, 3)$ (for instance) ? I mean, why only these two cases ? Technically, we would have to test 36 possibilities (36 couples of images), but with symmetry we only have to test 18 of them ... but I really don't understand how we get rid of 16 of them ...

Comment: @ArthurFilippi: You can't map both elements to the cyclic group of order $3$, because then the map is definitely not surjective. You can't map either element to the identity (same reason); you can't map both to the same element of order $2$ (same). You need to map them to a *generating set*, and the two types of generating sets for $S_3$ with two elements are (i) a 3-cycle and a 2-cycle; or (ii) two distinct 2-cycles. If the two 2-cycles are $(ab)$ and $(ac)$, then you can conjugate by an inner automorphism of $S_3$ to make them be $(1,2)$ and $(1,3)$.